# How to use Collection in datatable, using Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, collections, datatable

Hi I'm writing a project to allow for all specific lessons from the Lesson table to be displayed individually on a page. So all the Golf lessons would be on a golf page, and all the tennis on another, etc. Below is the Bean I have used

```
    //collects the lessons for specific sport number
    public Collection<Lesson> getLessonForSpecificSport(){
    Map<String, String> parameter=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
            getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    //parse the sport=x from the url to an integer
    int sportNumber = Integer.parseInt(parameter.get("sport"));

    //if sport number is equal to zero, display all lessons
    if (sportNumber==0)
    {
        return (Collection<Lesson>) this.getLessonList();
    }
    //else display the lessons corresponding to the value within sportNumber
    else
    {
        //return the sport.getLessonCollection() result
        return em.find(Sport.class, sportNumber).getLessonCollection(); 
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is how I would be able to render this on the page using dataTable, The latest attempt was this but nothing comes up on the page when I run Netbeans

```
  <h:dataTable value="#{getLessonForSpecificSport.lesson}" var="item">
  <h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
       Class no
  </f:facet>
  <f:param name="sportno" value="#{lesson.sportno}" />                      
  </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{listBean.lessonForSpecificSport}" var="lesson">
  <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
        Class no
     </f:facet>
     <h:outputText value="#{lesson.sportno}" />                      
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

or

```
<h:dataTable value="#{listBean.lessonForSpecificSport}" var="lesson">
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
       Class no
    </f:facet>
    #{lesson.sportno}"                    
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Supposing there is a method in class `Lesson` called `getSportno()`, and that the backing bean name is `listBean`.

Please notice that if the `Lesson` method is called `getSportNo()`, you should use `#{lesson.sportNo}` in the dataTable, instead. I.e. the method name is case sensitive, and only the first letter after the *get* prefix is used in lowercase.